# How to make a clean template and pass multiple items to it?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I usually store my underscore's templates inside an array like this:

```
var tmpl = [
  _.template('...'),
  _.template('...'),
  _.template('...'),
]
```

Now I came in a situation where I was using each loop inside a template but want to move it to this array. The static HTML template was simple:

```
var items = [
  [name: 'First'],
  [name: 'Second'],
  [name: 'Third']
];

var html = '<tr>';

_(items).each(function(item) {
  html += '<td>'+item.name+'</td>';
});

html += '</tr>';
```

It's working good but is ugly and so I would like to move it into **tmpl** list of templates. So I have this:

```
var tmpl = [
  _.template('<tr><td>#{name}</td></tr>');
]
```

**So my question** - how to I build a for loop inside a template and pass the whole object to it?

I have rewritten my custom template, but it looks actually much much worse and doesn't work and the syntax is just a mess. This is what I am talking about:

```
var tmpl = {
    vertical: _.template(
      '<table data-src="#{id}">'+
        '#{_(items).each(function(item) { }'+
        '<tr>'+
          '<td style="width: #{item.width}px; height: #{item.height}px">'+
            '#{item.text}'+
          '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '#{ });}'+
      '</table>'
    )
  }
```

instead of simple and plain:

```
var table = '<table data-src="'+id+'">';
      $(tds).each(function() {
        table += '<tr>';
          table += '<td style="width: '+$(this).width()+'px;height: '+$(this).height()+'px;">';
            table += $(this).html();
          table += '</td>';
        table += '</tr>';
      });
      table += '</table>';
```

Note that my syntax of template is different. Not `<%= var %>` but `#{var}`:

```
_.templateSettings = { interpolate : /#\{(.+?)\}/g };
```

and I would like to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do using underscore's functional abilities:

```
var row = _.template('<td><td style="width: #{width}px; height: #{height}px">'+
                     '#{text}</td></tr>');

function rows ( items ) {
  return _.reduce( _.map( items, function( item ) { return row( item ); }),
                   function( row, memo ) { return row.concat( memo ); }, "");
}

var table = _.template('<table data-src="#{ id }">#{ rows(items) }</table>');
```

Note that the `rows` function could be implemented using a for loop but the key here is that it is defined within a function and it is that function that you use from inside the `table` template. This function is then evaluated when rendering the template, calling the template for each row and concatenating them.

Underscore's templating engine is really minimal. If you want something a little bit more elaborate, with built-in iterators and block helpers, I would recommend having a look at [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com).

Anyhow, I think that this solution keeps the logic well separated from the actual markup to be generated and thus clear and easy to maintain.